# R markdown indentation not consistent after adding a table in between

Tags: r, markdown, indentation

I have been searching for the solution for a long time. The indentation changed whenever I add a table in between as you can see in the picture. I am not sure where I did wrong.

---

```
title: "Markdown_file"
author: "MZ"
date: "10/27/2019"
output: pdf_document
---


1.  abc dd dd 
    (a) adb
    (b) dwd

|    |   A| B |  C | 
|---:|---:|--:|---:|
|a   |  1 | 2 |  3 |
|b   |  1 | 3 |  3 |
|c   |  1 | 3 |  3 |

    (c) ddd
    (d) dddw
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your input RMarkdown file?

Comment: Hi sobysel, I added my code. Can you take a look again? Thanks!